# Block callback crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I have a custom NSOperation subclass that I use for making HTTP requests. It accepts a block-based callback that is executed when the NSOperation completes. Everything works accordingly, but I'm experiencing a strange, intermittent crash when trying to execute my completion callback. I've read a lot of block-based EXEC_BAD_ACCESS issues are caused by not correctly copying a block when passing it to additional methods.

I believe my issue relates to how I'm making use of blocks. I'll include a standard use case for my application below. The root of my issue is likely down to an ownership misunderstanding where blocks are concerned.

```
// Perform a HTTP request to a specified endpoint and declare a callback block
[self performRequestToEndpoint:@"endpoint" completion:^(HTTPResponse *response) {
    NSLog(@"Completed with response: %@", response);
}];

// A helper function to avoid having to pass around too many parameters
- (void)performRequestWithEndpoint:(NSString *)endpoint completion:(void (^)(HTTPResponse *response))completionBlock
{
    // Make our HTTP request and callback our original completion block when done
    [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:endpoint completion:^(HTTPResponse *response) {
        if(![response error])
        {
            // Call our original completion block
            completionBlock(response);
        }
    ];
}
```

When a callback block is assigned via the requestWithMethod:path:completion: method, it's copied like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^operationCompletionBlock)(HTTPResponse *response);
```

Here's the point of the crash:

```
- (void)callCompletionBlockWithResponse:(id)response
{
    if(self.operationCompletionBlock && !self.isCancelled)
    {
        self.operationCompletionBlock(response); // crashes here (intermittently)
    }

    [self finish];
}
```

Attached below is the stack trace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2403, 0x0000000000000000, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0000000000000000
    frame #1: 0x00007f946b53ed01
    frame #2: 0x0000000102da7cf7 Project`-[HTTPRequest callCompletionBlockWithResponse:] + 215 at HTTPRequest.m:402
    frame #3: 0x0000000102da79e7 Project`__44-[HTTPRequest connectionDidFinishLoading:]_block_invoke_0 + 423 at HTTPRequest.m:381
    frame #4: 0x00007fff956fea86 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
    frame #5: 0x00007fff957008f6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 308
    frame #6: 0x00007fff8f07ce7c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1724
    frame #7: 0x00007fff8f07c486 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    frame #8: 0x00007fff94f1a4d3 HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
    frame #9: 0x00007fff94f21781 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355
    frame #10: 0x00007fff94f2160e HIToolbox`BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
    frame #11: 0x00000001032a6e31 AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 659
    frame #12: 0x00000001032a6735 AppKit`-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
    frame #13: 0x00000001032a3071 AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 470
    frame #14: 0x000000010351f244 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 867
    frame #15: 0x0000000102d69512 Project`main + 34 at main.m:13
    frame #16: 0x0000000102d694e4 Project`start + 52
```

Comment: you are actually using the property to set it, right? e.g. `self.operationCompletionBlock = completionBlock;` not setting it on the instance variable directly? e.g. `operationCompletionBlock = completionBlock;`

Comment: Yep! It's set exactly as you described `self.operationCompletionBlock = completionBlock;`

Comment: Can't see anything that's wrong. Maybe you should show the requestWithMethod:path:completion: method

Comment: Are you sure the bad access is on the block itself, and not inside the block? Is the block body just the NSLog statement you pasted above?

Comment: On a hunch, I wrapped my completionCallback in a dispatch_async that runs via dispatch_get_main_queue() and this seems to clear up the crash. As I stated earlier, I think this may be an ownership issue, given that I'm referencing self and have blocks within blocks. By executing the callback on the main queue, I'm able to avoid the crash. But if anyone could explain explicitly why this is the case, I'd be interested. Otherwise I'll add this as an answer.

Comment: How you are assigning completion block to self.operationCompletionBlock

Answer (score 3):

This is a shot in the dark. You have two completion blocks, only one of which you explicitly copy (using the property). My mental model says that the `completionBlock` passed to `performRequestWithEndpoint:completion:` *should be* captured in the scope of the block you pass on. But I know some paranoid people who might try this:

```
- (void)performRequestWithEndpoint:(NSString *)endpoint 
                        completion:(void (^)(HTTPResponse *response))completionBlock
{
    void (^copiedBlock)(HTTPResponse *response) = [completionBlock copy];

    [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:endpoint completion:^(HTTPResponse *response) {
        if(![response error] && copiedBlock) {
            copiedBlock(response);
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: this worked for me pretty well, only thing is a typo in the code - instead of `void (^copiedBlock)(HTTPResponse *response))` should be `void (^copiedBlock)(HTTPResponse *response)`, thanks!

Comment: Syntax correction valid, thanks. The original grammar is better, IMO.